# ChromeIpass and Keepass

Tags: google-chrome, keepass

I am lost.  I want to use Keepass2 on my Ubuntu 12.04.
I got Keepass 2.24 finally loaded.  Using 2 dll instead of the .plgx for the plugin.  When I tried the plgx file, it couldn't find the plugin.  But that was before I loaded Keepass 2.24.
Now I have the chromeIpass extension loaded in chrome.  But when I click it, nothing happens.
Keepass2 recognizes the KeepassHttp plug in but there are no options with it.

Are you confused yet?  I am.  I have been searching the internet.  I try first one set of dlls and then the next.

I am getting one error message I took a pictures of it.

[image]

It looks like the newtonsoft.json is not working?

I would love any help anyone can give me!

Comment: http://imgur.com/1nVa9ND  I think this is the picture.

Comment: When I try to open  localhost:19455 in chrome I also get the same error message about newtonsoft.json file

Comment: I tried the plgx file after I updated to the keepass 2.24 and it still didn't work.

Comment: Well I think I got it working.  I followed the directions from this site. But also had to install git.  http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/installing-keepass2-on-ubuntu-linux-11-10-to-work-in-google-chrome-via-keepasshttp/